# Add a column to a stacked pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I would like to add a *days* column next to *amax* column and calculate the difference in days between *amin* and *amax*.

Creating a new column this way has been unsuccessful

```
df["dates"]["diff"] = df["dates"]["amax"]-df["dates"]["amin"]
```

Here you can see [an example of my dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap8cG.jpg)

I created the dataframe using the following code:

```
gb = stock_prices.groupby(['stock_name'])
df = gb.agg({'date' : [np.min, np.max]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset `multiindex` in columns and then add new column `diff`:

```
print df
                     activity       date     name
0                       slept 2014-12-02     Elon
1                     tripped 2013-08-04     Bill
2                       spoke 2012-05-08    Larry
3                        swam 2015-04-11     Elon
4                     spooked 2014-12-09     Jeff
5                       liked 2009-10-23    Larry
6                    whistled 2013-09-21    Larry
7                      up dog 2011-01-02     Bill
8                      smiled 2013-07-28    Larry
9                     donated 2014-11-19     Elon
10  grant men paternity leave 2015-10-24  Marissa
11                    fondled 2013-08-24     Jeff
```

```
#aggregate to min and max date 
g = df.groupby(['name']).agg({'date' : [np.max, np.min]})
print g
              date           
              amax       amin
name                         
Bill    2013-08-04 2011-01-02
Elon    2015-04-11 2014-11-19
Jeff    2014-12-09 2013-08-24
Larry   2013-09-21 2009-10-23
Marissa 2015-10-24 2015-10-24

#reset columns multiindex
levels = g.columns.levels
labels = g.columns.labels
g.columns = levels[1][labels[1]]

g['diff'] = g['amax'] - g['amin']
print g
              amax       amin      diff
name                                   
Bill    2013-08-04 2011-01-02  945 days
Elon    2015-04-11 2014-11-19  143 days
Jeff    2014-12-09 2013-08-24  472 days
Larry   2013-09-21 2009-10-23 1429 days
Marissa 2015-10-24 2015-10-24    0 days
```

But if you dont want reset `multiindex` in columns use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print g
              date           
              amax       amin
name                         
Bill    2013-08-04 2011-01-02
Elon    2015-04-11 2014-11-19
Jeff    2014-12-09 2013-08-24
Larry   2013-09-21 2009-10-23
Marissa 2015-10-24 2015-10-24

g.loc[:, ('date', 'diff')] =  g.loc[:, ('date', 'amax')] - g.loc[:, ('date', 'amin')]
print g
              date                     
              amax       amin      diff
name                                   
Bill    2013-08-04 2011-01-02  945 days
Elon    2015-04-11 2014-11-19  143 days
Jeff    2014-12-09 2013-08-24  472 days
Larry   2013-09-21 2009-10-23 1429 days
Marissa 2015-10-24 2015-10-24    0 days
```